# Pressed state of android selector is not working

Tags: android, selector

I made android and arduino applications that control my standing desk. I upload this project on github(https://github.com/neosarchizo/MyStandingDesk)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_button" />
</selector>
```

I wanted to use selector for buttons in MainActivity. If I press some button then an image of the button must be changed. But It didn't work. So I programatically change an image of the button by checking MotionEvent.

```
btnDown.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        btnDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_button_pressed);
                        sendCommand("a");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        btnDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_button);
                        sendCommand("s");
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Also I wrote following codes for selector in the layout xml file.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnDown"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_margin="30dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_down_button" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this

```
android:src="@drawable/selector_down_button"
```

to

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_down_button"
```

You would probably want to enable the Pressed state when you get ACTION_DOWN event and disable it when you get the ACTION_UP event.

```
  btnDown.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            btnDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_button_pressed);
                            sendCommand("a");
                            view.setPressed(true);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            btnDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_button);
                            sendCommand("s");
                            view.setPressed(false);
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Already I tried this. But it didn't work also. Please clone my project and test it.

Comment: now check my updated answer i have tested it.it's working perfect.

Comment: Can I solve this problem without `view.setPressed()`?

Comment: In the onTouch() method, return false. This will tell Android that the OnTouchListener is not responsible for handling the gesture that's why withoud this it will not possible.

Comment: can you try with click event if you use click event then it's possible

Comment: But I want to use pressed event. If I use click event then How do I know whether pressed event triggerd?

Comment: yes that's true but without that it is not possible.it's all about android handling the gesture.

Comment: one solution come's in my mind if you can do it that way it is possible

Comment: take linearlayout and add button in that now don't set selector change Linera layout and butto background image on key up and down event

Comment: I don't understand clearly. Is right following steps? 1) add linearlayout 2) add button into the layout 3) don't set selector drawable to the layout and the button 4) Then how do I change an image? Programmatically?

Comment: 1)LinearLayout is for same as Selector and 2)ImageButton is changing background on touch 
1)Take Main LinearLayout 
2)Take ImageButton into LinearLayout
3)Now on Action_Down Set background of LinearLayout as well Button
4)Now Same do it for ActionUp

Comment: I give up!! Thank you. Because of me, you spent much time.

Comment: `view.setPressed()` is the only thing you should do to make this work

Answer (score 2):

Just try this

```
 android:background="@drawable/selector_down_button"
```

Set selector as a `background`